# Delete files I found on pc

Tags: windows-7

I somehow found a file IconCahe.db, data base file; it contains 5,744 KB (looks a lot to me?). Should I delete it?
Sorry I am a70 year old man with basic badly informed on computers, thanks

Comment: That's part of Windows and it's needed.

Comment: If you don't know what it is, leave it alone.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 maintains a *cache* of icons in the following location:

`C:\Users\<user-name>\AppData\Local\IconCache.db`

When Windows needs to draw icons (e.g. on the desktop, in the Start Menu, in an application) it gets them from this cache.

If you delete IconCache.db, Windows will re-create the file and, over time, re-build its contents. So there's no need to delete this file.

Answer (score 0):

The file is automatically created by windows to cache icons.  You can safely delete it, but Windows will rebuild the file when it needs to display icons again.  5,744KB is only 5MB and not much to worry about with the size of drives today.  If you are looking to reclaim space on your hard drive I recommend [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download)

Answer (score 0):

It just an cache file, that means it just a file that stores data for more rapid access of an program, system, app, almost anything will create cache files to make it load faster, and etc, you can safely remove it however it will be build again for the reasons i told you, 5,744KB is only 5MB which is nothing actually.
Values for disks drive spaces are:

Byte = 8 Bits(you don't need to care about bits really)

Kilobyte(KB) = 1,024 bytes (2 or 3 paragraphs of text.)

Megabyte(MB) = 1,024 Kilobytes (4 books with 200 pages)

Gigabyte (GB)= 1,024 Megabytes (256 MP3 audio files with 4MB average file size)

Terabyte (TB)=1,024 Gigabytes (40 25GB Blu-ray discs)

I will stop here, today mostly all PC's come with more than 100GB of disk space, so as you can see 5MB is literally nothing! If you need space you want to delete heavy files aka more than 100MB usually,but beware if you don't know what is it, don't delete it.
And don't be afraid of ask, google is your best friend and you'll see that computers aren't that hard!Sorry for bad english